# How can I get metrics such as incoming and outcoming traffic with Apache servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Suppose a network consisting of hubs A, B, C, D ... and X. I am looking for ways to visualize how users use the network such as incoming, outgoing and other metrics. In Apache logs, I can see some errs if something did not work but I have no realistic picture about such a system in  general i.e. how the system actually works. I am looking for some sort of flow-analysis and I would like to get pure data to create some graph. Then analyze the graph with some metrics where I do not even know the right metrics, perhaps some dispersion metric. My goal is to create some sort of objective way to judge quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

etherape? mrtg? argus? pastMon? How much data are you gathering, how long do you want to store it? You've not given a lot of information.

However network monitoring is not the solution to diagnosing application faults. Maybe you're looking for mod_security.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is specific enough to actually answer. Here's a couple things to try and why:

- [Boundary](http://boundary.com/). Collector sends granular stats to Boundary, where you can see the impact of traffic flows and ideally, identify anomalies.
- [Scout](http://scoutapp.com/). Automatically measures per-server network stats and makes it really easy to write a [custom plugin](https://scoutapp.com/info/developers) of your own.
- [Blitz.io](http://blitz.io/). If you're mostly focused on HTTP, this will at least let you discover how your site degrades under load.

There isn't a single "objective way to judge quality," but based on your question, any or all of these will be a huge improvement from where you are.